# Undefined behavior when exceeding a certain matrix length using C language and open MP

Tags: c, openmp

The C program reads a matrix and determines the average of a column and if that value has occurred in that column. It works with small matrices but it doesn't with medium and large Matrices. The results I get are random and changes from execution to another even if the input is the same.
The sequential version works fine.
Also is there an equivalent of the C++ collapse directive in C?
I got no errors or warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

// user call the application from the command line and 
// inputs the length of the square array and the name of the input file

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ii,i, sum = 0, newi = 0, k = 0;
    int n, I, J;
    int L;
    L = atoi(argv[1]);
    int size;
    size = L * L;
    newi = size;
    char *str = NULL;
    double *d = NULL;
    double **ptr;
    ptr = &(d);
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    d = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[2], "r") : stdin;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    float local_sum, *avg;
    int matches2;
    if (!fp)
    {  //validate file open for reading 
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 1;i < argc;i++)
    {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
        {
            sscanf(str, "%lf", &d[k]);//storing the values as double in a vector 
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose(fp);   // close file if not stdin 

    printf("number of elements in the file is %d\n", newi);
    printf("number of elements in  a row is %d\n", L);

    int r = L;
    float **arr = (float **)malloc(r * sizeof(float *));
    int w = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
        arr[i] = (float *)malloc(r * sizeof(float));

    avg = (float *)malloc(L * sizeof(float *));
    //#pragma omp parallel for // This didn't work 
    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        //#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:w) // This didn't work 
        for ( j = 0; j < L; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = d[w];
            //printf("  %lf  %d \n  \n ", arr[i][j],w);
            w += 1;
        }
    }
    // 1 ) finding the average of each column
    // 2 ) comparing the indivual values to the average
    // 3 ) writing the matching results
    // 1 ) finding the average of each column

    int j ;


    //#pragma omp parallel for 
    for (j = 0; j < L; j++)
    {
        local_sum = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for shared (local_sum)
        for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            local_sum += arr[i][j];
            // no data dependency or a race condition
            //printf("local sum is %lf\n", local_sum);//delete
            //printf("Hello from thread %d of %d in local summation \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
        }
        //control       printf("local sum is %lf\n", local_sum);//delete                                                
        avg[j] = local_sum / L;// every j is unique to the running threads and there's no race condition 
        // 2 )comparing the indivual values to the average
        int matches = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel for  shared(matches)
            for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
            {  
                if (arr[i][j] == avg[j])
                    matches++;
                    //printf("Hello from thread %d of %d in matches calculation now is %d \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(),matches);
                }
                //fclose(fp);

                //control       printf("matches are  %d\n", matches);

        // 3 )writing the results
            matches2 = matches;

        omp_set_dynamic(0);

        #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(matches2) num_threads(1)
        
        {
            if (matches2 >= 1)

            {

                printf("we have a match in column %d  the value matches the average of elements in the column.(%d time/s) \n", j, matches2);
                // creating the output file and opening it to Write without deleting previous results
                fptr = fopen("D:\\OutputfromFile.txt", "a");
                //fptr = fopen(*argv[3], "a"); This did not work ! 
                fprintf(fptr, "We have a match in column %d ", j);// writing results to the file
                fprintf(fptr, " , we matched  %d time/s\n", matches2);// writing results to the file
                //printf("Hello from thread %d of %d \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
            }

            else
            {
                //if (j+1==L)continue;
                //control           printf("we have no matches ");
                // creating the output file and opening it to Write without deleting previous results
                fptr = fopen("D:\\OutputfromFile.txt", "a");
                fprintf(fptr, "We have no matches ");// writing results to the file 
                //fprintf(fptr, " , we matched  %d time/s\n", matches);// writing results to the file
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code a bit? Also, if the values always change, you may want to check you are not out of bounds on an array or forgetting to dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean ? remove the white spaces ? should I reduce the code ?

Comment: I have done it for now, next time you should do it, that shows how interested you are in getting answer, and you should consider using functions instead of throwing everything in `main` function

Comment: Undefined behavior is probably due to lack of error handling. Check the return values of `malloc`, `fopen`, etc.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the C++ collapse directive. There is an OpenMP collapse directive which is the same for C and C++.

Comment: Having nested ```#pragma omp parallel for``` directives is mostly a bad idea. In the special case that the outer loop doesn't contain enough iterations to balance the work between the threads **and** dynamic/guided scheduling doesn't do the trick **and** the collapse directive isn't applicable due to the inner loop range being dependent on the outer loop iteration variable, one might use these nested pragmas while also taking care that the total number of threads doesn't exceed the number of processors via the ```num_threads()``` clause.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having a parallel region with num_threads(1)?

Comment: Writing to file should **not** be inside any parallel region, as long as you don't have a specialized parallel file system. Therefore you should put the column results in arrays inside the parallel region and then in the end write to file sequentially. If possible, don't mix calculation and file access.

Comment: And last but not least, it might not be an issue here, but I think that explicitly stating for every variable if it is shared or private is a good default. To not forget to do this one can just add ```default(none)``` to any ```#pragma omp parallel``` such that the compiler wont let you not specify these things explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Paul ,your suggestion makes sense and have helped a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code now works fine

1. I moved the writing to the file outside the parallel region.
2. made the outermost loop parallel instead of the nested ones.
3. made sure to remove any dependencies ( I could think of )and initialize variables
   inside the parallel loop.
4. handled the file opening process and potential failure properly
5. if I missed something please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ii, i, sum = 0, newi = 0, k = 0;
    int n, I, J;
    int L;
    L = atoi(argv[1]);
    int size;
    size = L * L;
    newi = size;
    char *str = NULL;
    double  *d = NULL;
    double  **ptr;
    ptr = &(d);
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    if (str == NULL) printf(" str memory allocation failed ");
    d = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    if (d == NULL) printf("  double  memory allocation failed ");
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[2], "r") : stdin;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    double   local_sum, *avg;
    int matches2;
    int *filearraymatches, *filearraytimes;
    filearraymatches = (int  *)malloc(L * sizeof(int  *));
    filearraytimes = (int  *)malloc(L * sizeof(int  *));

    if (!fp)
    {  //validate file open for reading 
        fprintf(stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }



    for (i = 1;i < argc;i++)
    {
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", str) != EOF)
        {
            //printf("%s\n", str);//just checking 
            sscanf(str, "%lf", &d[k]);//storing the values as  double  in a vector 
            k++;
        }


    }


    if (fp != stdin) fclose(fp);   // close file if not stdin 

    printf("number of elements in the file is %d\n", newi);
    printf("number of elements in  a row is %d\n", L);

    int r = L;
    double  **arr = (double  **)malloc(r * sizeof(double  *));
    int w = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    arr[i] = (double  *)malloc(r * sizeof(double));
    avg = (double*)calloc(L, sizeof(double));


#pragma omp parallel for default(none)//there is no race condition the variables are all independent 
    for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        
        for (j = 0; j < L; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = d[i*L+j];
            w += 1;
            
        }
        
    }

    // 1 ) finding the average of each column
    // 2 ) comparing the individual values to the average
    // 3 ) writing the matching results

// 1 ) finding the average of each column
    int j;
    int matches = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for private(local_sum) private(matches)  private(i) default(none) 

    for (j = 0; j < L; j++)
    {
        matches = 0;
        local_sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            local_sum += arr[i][j];
            // no data dependency or a race condition
            //printf("local sum is %lf\n", local_sum);//delete
            //printf("Hello from thread %d of %d in local summation \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());

        }   
                                            
        avg[j] = local_sum /(double) L;// every j is unique to the running threads and there's no race condition 
        //printf("local average is %lf\n", avg[j]);//correct calculation 


// 2 )comparing the individual values to the average
        for (i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] == avg[j]) 
            { matches++; 
            //printf("Hello from thread %d of %d in matches calculation now is %d \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), matches);
            //printf("matches are %d \n", matches);
            }
            //else printf("matches are %d \n  the element is %lf while the average is :%lf", matches, arr[i][j], avg[j]);
    
                ;//printf("Hello from thread %d of %d in matches we don't have a match  matches:  %d \n ", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads(), matches);
            //printf("avg[%d]= %lf \n", i, avg[i]);
            //printf("arr[i][j] =  %lf , average is %lf \n", arr[i][j], avg[j]);
                
            //printf("\n***********************matches are  %d\n", matches);
            
        }
// 3 )writing the results
        if (matches >0)
        {
            filearraymatches[j] = j;
            filearraytimes[j] = matches;
            //printf("we have a match in column %d  the value matches the average of elements in the column.(%d time/s the average in the column is %lf ) \n", j, matches, avg[j]);

        }
        else
        {
            filearraymatches[j] = 0;
            filearraytimes[j] = 0;
        }

    }

    char *path = argv[3];// Output file is a parameter
    // Writing results to the file 
    //fptr = fopen(path, "W");//assertion error
    fptr = fopen(path, "w");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        perror(path);
        printf("   fileerror  ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
       
    for (int i = 0;i < L;i++)
    {
            if (filearraytimes[i] != 0)
            {
                fprintf(fptr, "We have a match in column %d ", i);// writing results to the file
                fprintf(fptr, " , we matched  %d time/s\n", filearraytimes[i]);// writing results to the file
            }
            else fprintf(fptr, " We have no matches in this column %d \n",i);// writing results to the file 
    }
        fclose(fptr);
}
```